# Mongoose - Express JS - Update multiple fields in a collection from an array of ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a `Todo` collection that contains these data.

```
[
    {
      "_id": "608d5cfa11d24b1ae4710172",
      "completed": false,
      "createdAt": "2021-05-01T13:51:06.246Z",
      "text": "Todo 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "608d5cfc11d24b1ae4710173",
      "completed": false,
      "createdAt": "2021-05-01T13:51:06.246Z",
      "text": "Todo 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "608d5cfe11d24b1ae4710174",
      "completed": false,
      "createdAt": "2021-05-01T13:51:06.246Z",
      "text": "Todo 3"
    },
    {
      "_id": "608d5cff11d24b1ae4710175",
      "completed": true,
      "createdAt": "2021-05-01T13:51:06.246Z",
      "text": "Todo 4"
    },
    {
      "_id": "608d5d0a11d24b1ae4710176",
      "completed": false,
      "createdAt": "2021-05-01T13:51:06.246Z",
      "text": "Todo 5"
    },
    {
      "_id": "608d5d0b11d24b1ae4710177",
      "completed": true,
      "createdAt": "2021-05-01T13:51:06.246Z",
      "text": "Todo 6"
    }
  ]
```

I want to make a way so that I can update multiple objects of them from an array of `id`s.

For example, if I have an array of `["608d5cfa11d24b1ae4710172", "608d5cfc11d24b1ae4710173", "608d5cfe11d24b1ae4710174"]`

Normally, what I would do in order to update a value in each one of these is to use this:

```
await Todo.updateMany({
    _id: { 
         $in: ["608d5cfa11d24b1ae4710172", "608d5cfc11d24b1ae4710173", "608d5cfe11d24b1ae4710174"]
    }
}, {
   $set: {
        completed: true,
        text: "something"
   }
});
```

but what if I want to update multiple values in them that are not static values.
To demonstrate my point, if I have this array:

```
[
    {
      completed: true,
      text: "update"
    },
    {
      completed: false,
      text: "updated todo"
    },
    {
      completed: true
    }
]
```

then how can I update for each id its corresponding update?
So I would have something like this:

```
await Todo.updateMany({
    _id: { 
         $in: ["608d5cfa11d24b1ae4710172", "608d5cfc11d24b1ae4710173", "608d5cfe11d24b1ae4710174"]
    }
}, {
   $set: [
    {
      completed: true,
      text: "update"
    },
    {
      completed: false,
      text: "updated todo"
    },
    {
      completed: true
    }
]
});
```

My current solution is to loop through them like this

```
const promises = [
    {
      id: "608d5cfa11d24b1ae4710172",
      completed: true,
      text: "update"
    },
    {
      id: "608d5cfc11d24b1ae4710173",
      completed: false,
      text: "updated todo"
    },
    {
      id: "608d5cfe11d24b1ae4710174",
      completed: true
    }
].map(({ id, text, completed }) => {
     const todo = {};
     if (text) todo.text = text;
     if (completed !== undefined) todo.completed = completed;
     promises.push(Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, todo));
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

I hope you get my point here, and thanks in advance.

Comment: its not possible with updateMany(), you can try [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).

Comment: @turivishal This actually works, thank you